# Laravel Cashier Stripe Trial creates new subscriptions, allows exploit

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel Cashier to add stripe payments (subscriptions) for the premium version of my web app. Users are offered a 5-day free trial (card in advance).

Now what happens is, I create a subscription using:

```
$user->newSubscription('premium','monthly')->trialDays(5)->create($stripeToken,['email' => $user->email], "")
```

Works really well, but let's say the user cancels his subscription within the trial period.. He will be on the 'grace' period, let's say for 4 more days..

When these days are passed, user will lose account benefits, as the trial will expire and subscription is cancelled.

But, after that, if the user wants to subscribe again, since $subscription->resume() is only available during the grace period, I would have to create a subscription using $user->newSubscription, generating a new subscription on the table and a new trial period.. allowing them to cancel again, wait 5 days, create another one and repeat this getting free trial days forever..

Is there a way to "resume" an existing subscription when it is cancelled and grace period is over?

Comment: Sure. Don't call `trialDays` for users who've already had a subscription once. You should have a record of their previous subscription.

Comment: Still another row will be created on the "subscriptions" table and on stripe panel..  Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that's appropriate. It *is* a new subscription.

Comment: one more question, if I call trialDays(0) is it the same as not calling it?

Comment: Testing here, trialDays(0) will still give 5 days, it's a bit confusing because there is also the trial days you set on the stripe panel  (on the plan) seems like redundant information, not really sure which one is used.

Comment: @raphadko Similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887417/laravel-cashier-should-i-add-a-trial-period-in-stripe-too