# Laravel Cashier: should I add a trial period in Stripe too?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Quoting [Laravel Cashier documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing#subscription-trials):

> If you would like to offer trial periods to your customers while still collecting payment method information up front, You should use the trialDays method when creating your subscriptions.

Assuming I want to add a 30 days trial period to my subscriptions, I can create a subscription with this code:

```
$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')
        ->trialDays(30)
        ->create($stripeToken);
```

As a Stripe user, **should I add a trial period in Stripe plan too?**

[image]

I'm not sure to understand the logic of Laravel Cashier here. It seems redundant to declare something at two different places.

Comment: I would say its not necessary. If you're adding trial days at the time of subscription creation, that will take precedence over the trial days defined on a plan anyway!

Comment: Yes! I tried and it works. You can submit your comment as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say its not necessary. If you're adding trial days at the time of subscription creation ([trial_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription-trial_end) parameter when using the API directly), that will take precedence over the trial days defined on a plan anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% satisfied with these answers, since the question was specifically asking about using **Cashier**.

Creating a subscription using Cashier will always set a trial_end

```
protected function buildPayload()
{
    return array_filter([
        'billing_cycle_anchor' => $this->billingCycleAnchor,
        'coupon' => $this->coupon,
        'metadata' => $this->metadata,
        'plan' => $this->plan,
        'quantity' => $this->quantity,
        'tax_percent' => $this->getTaxPercentageForPayload(),
        'trial_end' => $this->getTrialEndForPayload(),
    ]);
}
```

This `trial_end` will either be "now" (no trial) by default or whatever you pass optionally in `->trialDays(XXX)`.

The trial period that is defined within Stripe seems to be **ignored**.

I agree, the expected behaviour should be that what you pass via cashier will take precedence over the trial days defined on a plan. However this doesn't seem to be the case. (cashier v8.0.1)

Comment: I agree that it is a good point that the configuration in Stripe is ignored. So, the only way to create a subscription that matches with Stripe is to first fetch the plan details from Stripe (is there a Cashier method for this? looks to me like need to use Stripe direct call) and then pass to Cashier. Very clunky.

Comment: This is the most important answer here - since SubscriptionBuilder sends trial_end in each payload, if you DON'T specify a trial duration, it sends null, which essentially strips out the default trial period you set in Stripe anyway. This can be dangerous if you expect your default to take effect, only to have it nullified by default in Cashier requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a trial period in stripe then there is no need to do it in code. If you you don't want trial every time someone subscribes you might want to have it in code.